# How do I connect webcam to OpenCV in linux in docker from windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, docker, webcam

I want to package my OpenCV program in Linux to somebody who only use windows to test. After some surveys, I find that docker may be a suitable way to put all my dependencies and program together to give it to someone else.

now I use docker toolbox because docker for windows may have some problem to use if I ( or other people ) already have virtual machines.

I follow some tutorial like [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-docker-image-ubuntu-macos-windows/) but now I find I have no way to connect the webcam via USB port. I cannot find the counterpart command in windows like

> docker run --device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0

comment in Reddit says follow command should work but I tried and nothing happened

> docker run -it -d --name wxapi --privileged -v
>   /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb wxapi

I tried the webcam connection by writing a simple python code like:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.isOpened()
```

and I open the USB option in the setting of the virtual machine. Since the VideoCapture(0) function return no exception alarm , the camera is never open and cap.isOpened() is always return false.

What should I do to connect my USB webcam from windows 10 to OpenCV in linux docker toolbox ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?